# нужно сделать такую анимацию. Помогите пожалуйста!!! https://tympanus.net/Development/LineMenuStyles/#Alonso

Tags: html, css

```
<! DOCTYPE html>


<head>
<style>
.menu--alonso .menu__item {
margin: 0;
}

.menu--alonso .menu__link {
width: 120px;
height: 3em;
text-align: center;
color: #b5b5b5;
-webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
transition: color 0.3s;
}

.menu--alonso .menu__link:hover,
.menu--alonso .menu__link:focus {
color: #929292;
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item--current .menu__link {
 color: #d94f5c;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
transition: color 0.5s;
}

.menu--alonso .menu__line {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
width: 120px;
height: 2px;
pointer-events: none;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-width: 0 45px;
background: #d94f5c;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
transition: transform 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1.22);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.01, 0, 1.22);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(1).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(2).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(3).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(4).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(300%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(300%, 0, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(5).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(400%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(400%, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width:55em) {
.menu--alonso .menu__line {
    top: 3em;
 }

   .menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(1).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   }

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(2).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 3em, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(3).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 6em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 6em, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(4).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 9em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 9em, 0);
}

.menu--alonso .menu__item:nth-child(5).menu__item--current ~ .menu__line {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 12em, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 12em, 0);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/codrops/LineMenuStyles/

Comment: где? я не понимаю.напишите пожалуйста, готовый код, очень срочно! кто разбирается в  этом, вам же не сложно, а мне просто сдать и забыть

Comment: серьезно, я пробовала, но вот так только открывается file:///F:/1%20(3).html

Comment: не вышло((( скиньте пожалуйста((

Comment: спасибо, но я так понимаю тут готовый код, но он почему-то не дейтсвует

Comment: ну он неправильно отображается, если вам видно- вот file:///F:/1%20(3).html

Comment: нет, а вы можете что надо в этом коде дописать?

Comment: @Diana  он же рабочий код,  я не вижу что вы там делаете ..и не могу помочь ... скачайте team viewer и я помогу и покажу что и не так

Comment: вот готовый код в самом начале, что я расписала, наверно там что-то еще добавить надо, проверьте